# Printing a WPF BitmapImage

Tags: .net, wpf, printing, imaging

What's the best way to print a BitmapImage?  I come from a background in System.Drawing so I was thinking about converting it to a Bitmap and then printing it, but I'm thinking there's probably a better way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Building upon Drew's answer, it is best to measure and arrange the container that is handed to the PrintVisual method. This will prevent an image that is larger than a 8.5 x 11 sheet of paper from being cut off. Here is an example of how I printed an image that was partially visible on-screen:

```
PrintDialog dlg = new PrintDialog();
bool? result = dlg.ShowDialog();

if (result.HasValue && result.Value)
{
    ImageViewer.Measure(new Size(dlg.PrintableAreaWidth, dlg.PrintableAreaHeight));
    ImageViewer.Arrange(new Rect(new Point(0, 0), ImageViewer1.DesiredSize));

    dlg.PrintVisual(ImageViewer, "Print a Large Image");
}
```

ImageViewer in my example could be replaced with any UIElement container such as a stackpanel, canvas, grid, ect. ImageViewer.Source should be set to the BitmapImage that is ready to be printed.

I got the idea from this page:
http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/printing-in-wpf

Comment: Thank you very much. This resolved my problem with printing an image.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [the `PrintDialog` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.printdialog.aspx). All you should need to do is call [the `PrintVisual` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.printdialog.printvisual.aspx) passing in an [`Image`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.aspx) as the visual that has your `BitmapImage` as a source.

You may want to setup other printing options, but you'll discover those as you explore PrintDialog and related APIs.

Answer (score 0):

illogial's answer has the problem, that's always stretching the image to pagesize and cuts off some content at trying this.

Therefore i wrote a own solution, which only stretch(is this the right word?) if the image is to large, can use multiply copies and pageorientations.

Here is the [Code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63384548/1542368)